# Detect HTTP_USER_AGENT in asp

Tags: asp-classic, user-agent

I need in an asp site, detect if the device used is a tablet.
i'd like to know which user agent is use for this one

for now i do this

```
agent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")

    Set reg = New RegExp
    With reg
        .Pattern = "(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|pda|mobile|mini|palm)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    match = reg.Test(agent)

    If match Then
        session("IsMobileBrowser") = 1
    Else
        session("IsMobileBrowser") = 0
    End If
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are using this API to dectect mobile devices on our classic asp website and it works great.
https://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/#svn/JavaScript

Use DetectTierTablet function to detect tablets.

Also with very few changes to the code we were able to include it server side. Just had to replace:

```
if (navigator && navigator.userAgent)
    this.uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
```

with

```
if (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT").Item != null)
    this.uagent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT").Item.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: thanks but do you know the value according to a tablet device?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see your comment before today, but sorry I don't understand your question, can you explain ?